# Replacing hyphens in querystring via Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Due to a restriction with a URLRewrite module, I am replacing all whitespace in a querystring value with hyphens.
Server side I want to replace the hyphens back to whitespace, which is fine.

However, if there is a hyphen in the querystring (before I encode the value), when I decode the querystring, it removes ALL hyphens, include the one which is meant to be there.

So my question is, how do I achieve the following with a Regex/Regex in C#....

Example 1
.................................
Querystring: "a-search-term"
Decoded value: "a search term"

Example 2
.................................
Querystring: "a-hyphenated---search"
Decoded value: "a hyphenated - search"

Also, I'm open for suggestions as to how to handle something like...

Querystring: "up-for--discussion"
Decoded value: "up for -discussion"

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have the option of URL encoding the real hyphens before supplanting in your hyphens? For example, the string `"a hyphenated - search"` can become `"a-hyphenated-%2D-search"`, which should be a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do a simple string replace?

This should work for your basic scenarios but it's not the best solution:

```
string newstring = yourstring.Replace("-", " ").Replace("   ", " - ").Replace("  ", " -");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Server.UrlEncode("a search term"), no need to decode, asp.net will get the correct value when reading

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
However spec is dictating that we encode the values in Javascript, and we cannot use '+' to represent spaces due to the afore mentioned restriction

Comment: How about using %20 for spaces?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, try the escape/unescape functions

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html